# Why doesn't wireshark recognize the http text in my tcp request?

Tags: networking, pcap, tcp, pcap.net

I'm trying to send http data over a custom made pcap.net based tcp client.

Normally, when I send request via browser, in wireshark it looks like this:

[image]

However, when I send the same data over TCP myself, in wireshark the request looks like this:

[image]

and the server does not respond properly to it.

I'm attaching the data to TcpDatagraw via PayloadLayer, but it seems that something is missing.

What should I change so this works properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try appending 2 CRLFs (**\r\n\r\n**) at the end of the HTTP data